# Get top result of a Google search in Python

Tags: python, google-search, python-webbrowser

```
import webbrowser

x = input("Search something : ")

webbrowser.open(x)
```

Example: Who is the president of USA?

I want to print the top result that is Joe Biden in the terminal.

Comment: There are already plenty of modules that implement this. Depends if you want to implement it yourself for learning or fun, if you want to use webscrapping or an api, etc. But a very simple approach would be to correctly create a search url like this: https://www.google.com/search?q=who+is+the+president+of+the+usa

Comment: It is against Google's [Webmaster Guidelines](//developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/webmaster-guidelines) and [terms of service](//policies.google.com/terms/archive/20020906?hl=en) to submit programmatic search queries. Running this code against Google is likely to cause Google to show captcha for searches from your IP address.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`google-search`](https://pypi.org/project/google-search) library to do this. Here's the basic example of `google-search`:

```
from googlesearch.googlesearch import GoogleSearch
response = GoogleSearch().search("something")
for result in response.results:
    print("Title: " + result.title)
    print("Content: " + result.getText())
```

You may do further research about this library on your own. [Here's](https://googlesearch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?badge=latest) the documentation of this libary.

Or you can use [`google`](https://pypi.org/project/google/) module. Here's the basic example for this library:

```
from googlesearch import search

query = "Geeksforgeeks"
for j in search(query, num=10, stop=10, pause=2):
    print(j)
```

For further information you may look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/performing-google-search-using-python-code/).

Or you can learn `web-scraping`. From [here](https://www.edureka.co/blog/web-scraping-with-python/) you may start learning and make your own script. Another, [this](https://realpython.com/python-web-scraping-practical-introduction/) you may start from here as well.

Answer (score -1):

This script will make a request to the Google Search API and print the first result to the console.

```
const apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";

async function fetchGoogleSearch(query) {
  const response = await fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${apiKey}&cx=YOUR_SEARCH_ENGINE_ID&q=${query}`);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data.items[0];
}

const query = "What is the capital of France?";

const result = the capital of France Bangladesh(query);

console.log(result.title);
```

Comment: This is javascript, not python...